# Trigger to increment a column value after update in a column of same table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a table with two columns:

```
C1  |  C2
 1  |   3
```

Whenever `C1` gets updated to 0, `C2` should be incremented by 1.

I have developed a trigger:

```
create trigger increment
after update on T1
begin
  if new.C1=0 then
    update T1 set c2 = c2 +1;
  end if;
end;
```

But this raises an error whenever I try to update column C1:

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'T1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

I have only one update trigger on this table. How can I make this work?

Comment: Please don't use the Oracle tag for MySQL questions, it's for Oracle database. (If I got this wrong and your question is indeed about Oracle database, please [edit] your question to remove the MySQL tag and put the Oracle tag back in.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also change values using `new`. You just have to use not `after` but `before` trigger.

```
delimiter $$
create trigger increment
before update on T1
begin
    if new.C1=0 then
        set new.c2 = new.c2 +1;
    end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I added the `delimiter` clauses around the code. You also forget the `set` keyword before the assignment. +1 otherwise.

Comment: why cant we use after update ?

what does the error mean ? is it mutating table error ??

Comment: The idea of trigger is not to do an additional update of the table but to adjust the values so that we do additional things with one UPDATE. Actually my trigger differs a bit from yours. Do you really need to increment C2 column of all rows when C1 of one row becomes 0?

Comment: not of all rows , i just need to increment C2 column for the row whose C1 becomes 0 everytime..