# Use trigger to populate another column

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have two counters in a mysql table. I would like to have another column that contains the difference between counter column 1 and counter column 2. Could I use a trigger after counter column 2 is updated which will subtract the number in counter 2 from the number in counter 1 and put the results in count column 3? I would want to index count column 3 for queries.

Comment: Is [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47473/trigger-to-increment-a-column-value-after-update-in-a-column-of-same-table?rq=1) helpful?

Comment: @John M , Not really

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222044/column-calculated-from-another-column

Comment: @dfundako is right, you wanted make a [generated column](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=411) and not mess with triggers, I should've read this more clearly.

Comment: @dfundako Not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: What is your version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) in your `CREATE TABLE` statement to always have an up-to-date value:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    col1 INT NOT NULL,
    col2 INT NOT NULL,
    col3 INT AS (col1 - col2)
);
```

The column can be virtual or stored (virtual is default) and each has their own use cases as detailed in the link above.

Note: only applicable for MySQL 5.7.6 & higher.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I need without triggers at all.